# Was Yael Jewish?

Tags: genealogy, shoftim--book-of, yael

In Shoftim chapters 4 and 5 we learn of a woman named יָעֵל אֵשֶּׁת חֶבֶר הַקֵּינִי, Yael the wife of Chever the Kenite, who kills Sisra. In the song of Devorah, the Midrash (Ruth Rabba 1:8) and Gemara (Horiyot 10b) all seem to imply that she was Jewish, one reading has her as being a Shofeteth of the Jews (I'm not aware of anyone who claims any of the Shoftim were non-Jews), another expounds a moral lesson of the value of sinning for the sake of God (which she did by sleeping with Sisra).

I would like to know if there is an explicit source which states that Yael, the wife of Chever the Kenite was in fact Jewish.

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/849

Comment: also, wouldn't the kenites, as descendants of Jethro, have had the status of proselytes?

Comment: @Loewian I would assume that Sisra did not think she was Jewish, otherwise why would he enter her tent peacefully instead of killing her?

Comment: He may have been unaware of her religious allegiance and may have assumed her national allegiance, like that of her husband, had drifted against the Israelites.

Comment: Conversely, I suspect that her being midrashically listed amongst the shoftim, may just mean that she "judged" between Israel and its enemies, i.e. when she executed Sisra.

Comment: https://meirtv.com/en/qa-was-yael-jewish-070716--13345l -- see a rundown of the different opinions there

Comment: What is the source for her being *Shofetet*? it's very werid, since Devora explicitly 
 was the *Shofetet* a this time.

Comment: @Alaychem its a midrash based on the pairing with Shamgar in 5:6. See Rashi ad loc

Comment: @Loewian Did you ever find an answer about the Kenites? I recall learning different opinions if they are descended from Cain or not, which creates an indeterminacy in understanding who they were and where they stood, on top of the indeterminacy that already exists with Cain in the first place because there was some good that came out of Cain as well as evil. Were the Kenites Jews? Were the Kenites good that came out of Cain? Or just Jethro but mostly they were bad news?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the following source which says that Yael was a righteous convert

ילקוט שמעוני יהושע - פרק א - רמז ט . יש נשים חסידות גיורות הגר אסנת צפרה שפרה פועה בת פרעה רחב רות ויעל אשת חבר הקיני:

There are pious converts... Yael the wife of Chever the Kenite - Yalkut Shimoni: Joshua 1:9

---

In [this lecture](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/755099/rabbi-ari-zahtz/parshas-beshalach-why-such-a-long-haftorah-yael-s-connection-to-the-parsha/), at 22 minutes, Rabbi Zahtz states that Rav Yaakov Emden states that Yael was not Jewish