# What was the consequence of Yael's sin?

Tags: reward-punishment, capital-punishment, arayot, shoftim--book-of, yael

The gemarah (Horiyot 10b, Nazir 23b) states that Yael sinned for the sake of God in sleeping with Sisra. I would like to know what consequence, if any, there was for this sin. Was her husband obligated to divorce her? If she was not-Jewish ([related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108442/was-yael-jewish)) was she liable for the death penalty for committing adultery, in violation of the 7 Noahide laws?

Comment: According to the Meshech Chochma, her husband divorced her - cited here: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99#cite_note-8

Comment: Another "consequence" cited on that site in the name of the Ran and the Rema MiPano is that she was the ancestress of Rabbi Akiva.